# Фон только под текстом

Tags: css

Как сделать фон именно под текстом, не покрывая пространство между строк.
[image: Текст на элементе слайдера]

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/bz8yq/

```css
.ColorRed{
   background: red;
   }
```

```html
<span  class = "ColorRed">blablalbalbalba blablabla bla blablalbablablalbalbalbablablalbalbalbablablalbalbalba
  blablalbalbalbablablalbal<br>balbablablalbalbalbablablalbalbalbablablalbalbalbablablalbalbalbablablalbalbalba<br>blablalbalbalbablablalbalbalbablablalbalbalbablablalbalbalba
  <br>blablalbalbalbablablalbalbalbablablalbalbalbablablalbalbalbablablalbalbalbablablalbalbalbablablalbalbalbablablalbalbalba<br></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Так по умолчанию происходит со всеми строчными элементами:

```css
span {
  line-height: 2em;
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<span>Как сделать фон именно под текстом, не покрывая пространство между строк.
Как сделать фон именно под текстом, не покрывая пространство между строк. </span>
```